# Merge 2 PowerShell variables

Tags: powershell

I have 2 PowerShell variables that include data in the following format. For the first table:

```
UserName        Department
--------       ----------
X@Y.com          IT
```

and data in the following format in the second table:

```
Country       MobileNumber                         
-------       ------------
Singapore     +65 8xxxxxxx
```

and the other variable is the same with different column names and different content. I want to merge the 2 variables to have them in one single variable in that would be in the following format:

```
UserName        Department          Country       MobileNumber
--------        ----------          -------       ------------
```

Update:
The result of Ansgar commnet, generate it in the following format:

```
UserName            Department          Country                  MobileNumber
--------            ----------          -------                  ------------
{x@y.com, z@y.com}  {IT, Sales}         {Singapore, Singapore}    the same here
```

Comment: Please show a sample of the second variable as well

Comment: Please show output of `$var1 | Get-Member` and `$var2 | Get-Member`.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Done.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers The first variable type is: Selected.Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Resources.Models.Authorization.PSRoleAssignment. The other one is: Selected.Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Profile.Models.PSAzureSubscription

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you have individual objects in your two variables you could construct new objects from them like this:

```
$obj = New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{
    'UserName'     = $obj1.UserName
    'Department'   = $obj1.Department
    'Country'      = $obj2.Country
    'MobileNumber' = $obj2.MobileNumber
}
```

If you have *arrays* of objects (which, judging from your updated question, is the case) you need to build the objects in a loop. Note that this assumes an equal number of objects in *both* variables. Note also that you MUST ensure that both arrays are in the correct order, unless you have some criteria by which you can match objects from one array to the corresponding object from the other array.

```
$obj = for ($i=0; $i -lt $obj1.Count; $i++) {
    New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{
        'UserName'     = $obj1[$i].UserName
        'Department'   = $obj1[$i].Department
        'Country'      = $obj2[$i].Country
        'MobileNumber' = $obj2[$i].MobileNumber
    }
}
```

Comment: It works, but generates the output between {} not as the normal column. Can we manipulate the format to look like the one on the question?

Comment: @Krank Are your variables perhaps lists of objects? Are the property values arrays? Please update your question with sample output.

Comment: Done. Please recheck.

Comment: @Krank As suspected your original variables contain arrays of objects. Please do not omit important details like this from your question. Answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a new object and map the properties in a hashtable like this:

First, you have your variables with the data, in this example it is

```
    $Variable1
    $Variable2
```

Then we want to make a Hashtable, this will map the data in each of these two variables to a property in our new object, so we map the two properties `Username` and `Department` from the first variable and the `Country` and the `MobileNumber` from the second variable.

```
    $properties = @{
        'Username'=$Variable1.UserName;
        'Department'=$Variable1.Department;
        'Country'=$Variable2.Country;
        'MobileNumber'=$Variable2.MobileNumber;}
```

Lastly we create a new object, in this example I call the object `$User`. We tell this object to contain the properties for our Hashtable:

```
    $User = New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property $properties
```